# Background-Image isn't working on stylesheet but works fine inline

Tags: html, css, background-image

The image doesn't come up on the stylesheet, I've tried so many different things (changing to background

```
.vegeta {
height: 300px;
width: 300px;
padding: 10px;
background: url("images/vegeta.jpg");
}
```

However when I put it in the  tags on the html page the image shows. The stylesheet is definitely being called by the html document because the other changes show on the page, its just the image that isn't showing up.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: It must have something to do with the path.
How exactly is the image stored?

Comment: It may also be a misspelling or a text case problem.
Make sure the filename in the path is exactly identical to the image title.

Comment: Also, just to be sure. Put the image in the same location as the html page and then try `background: url("vegeta.jpg")`

Comment: Make sure the css is in the same dir as your html, or change the url in the css to ../images, or /images if on server.. you could check in your browser, F12 and tab network for errors

Comment: Its in the images folder, within the main project folder. I dont think its the path, because once I put this inline then it works fine. I also tried moving the img out of the sub-directory, put it in the main folder, removed the "images/" part and tried it but it still didn't work.

Comment: If it works inline, yet not in an external stylesheet, it would mean your stylesheet is not in the same directory as the html page. In the stylesheet the path is relative to the stylesheet, whereas inline it is relative to the html file. To omit this issue, you could store the  image as base64 string in the stylesheet.

Comment: Thank you, that was the issue. I used this:

`background: url("../images/vegeta.jpg");`

And it worked!

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should check all the directory location and spelling, these are the basic problems which we don't notice many time.

Use can use **background-image** instead of just **background** because CSS is updated, maybe this can help.

I hope this may help you! Otherwise you can tell me again with all the directory properly.